# XML Inflate error while inflating XML Resource inside RecycleViewAdapter

Tags: android

I'm getting following exception while inflating my XML resource as part of RecycleViewAdapter:

**Exception:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.xcv.poke, PID: 16410
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
```

***My PokeImageAdapter Adapter Class:***

```
package com.xcv.poke.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.xcv.poke.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.squareup.picasso.Target;


public class PokeImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PokeImageAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    //this context we will use to inflate the layout
    private Context mCtx;

    //we are storing all the products in a list
    private ArrayList<String> urlList;



    //getting the context and product list with constructor
    public PokeImageAdapter(Context mCtx, ArrayList<String> fileUrlLinkList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.urlList = fileUrlLinkList;

    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView imageViewHolder;
        ImageView imageView;
        ProgressBar progressBar;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageViewHolder = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_imageHolder);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);
            progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pb_loader);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //inflating and returning our view holder
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_pokemon_image_tile, null);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final ViewHolder mHolder = holder;
        final ProgressBar progressBar = holder.progressBar;


        final int currentPosition = position;
        //getting the product of the specified position
        final String currentItemURL = urlList.get(position);


        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Picasso.with(mCtx)
                .load(currentItemURL)
                .into(new Target() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                        mHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //stop progressbar here
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //stop progressbar here
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                    }
                });

//        Picasso.with(mCtx)
//                .load(new File(currentItem.getLinkURL()))
//                .into(holder.imageView);

//            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(resultBmpURl).resize(400, 400).into(bmImage);



    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return urlList.size();
    }


}
```

**My XML Resource: *cardview_pokemon_image_tile.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv_imageHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/img_holder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/pb_loader"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorGreen"
                    android:padding="10dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_thumbnail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="260dp"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />


            </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you added cardview implementation in the Gradle file?

Comment: Yes, Found out issue, it was `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`

Comment: Ok thats Great :)